# phalcon routing does not work properly

Tags: apache, ubuntu-12.04, phalcon, vhosts, phalcon-routing

I am having the same issue
My .htaccess file in project/ is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  ^$ public/    [L]
RewriteRule  (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

**server : apache**
and  the command "**a2enmod rewrite**" shows that "**Module rewrite already enabled**"
when i point the browser to project folder i can see the folder structure , when i point to project/public then i can see "Hello world." I am using ubuntu elementary os. Am i Following correctly or is there any error in my installation.

Comment: `I am having the same issue` ... same issue as?

Answer (score 1):

> when i point the browser to project folder i can see the folder structure , when i point to project/public then i can see "Hello world."

your server should be configured so you can't see the project folder from the browser, the root of your virtualhost should be the public folder

Answer (score 0):

Is IfModule closed?

What you see when you go to another uri? Phalcon's error or Apache 404?

Try to disable mod rewrite, restart apache and then enable it again

```bsh
a2dismod rewrite
service apache2 restart
a2enmod rewrite
service apache2 restart
```

I get this error to, but i don't know exactly how i fix it...